# Simplify $\int_a^b \mathrm{d}x_1 ...\mathrm{d}x_m \int_c^d \mathrm{d}y_1 ...\mathrm{d}y_n \prod_{i=1}^m \prod_{j=1}^n f(x_i y_j)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, large-deviation-theory

Let $a \le b$ and $c\le d$ be real numbers and $f$ a real function. I am struggling with an integral of the form:

$$I = 
\int_a^b \mathrm{d}x_1 ...\mathrm{d}x_m 
\int_c^d \mathrm{d}y_1 ...\mathrm{d}y_n
\prod_{i=1}^m \prod_{j=1}^n f(x_i y_j)$$

Can it be reduced to a single or double integration somehow?

I am interested in the large $m,n$ behavior of $I$. Specifically, suppose that the ratio $\alpha = m/n$ is fixed. Can we evaluate in general the limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \ln I$$

So far, these are the only reductions I've been able to do:

$$\begin{aligned}
  I & = \int_a^b \mathrm d x_1 \dots \mathrm d x_m \left( \int_c^d \mathrm d y
  \prod_{i = 1}^m f (x_i y) \right)^n\\
  & = \int_c^d \mathrm d y_1 \ldots \mathrm d y_m \left( \int_a^b \mathrm d x
  \prod_{j = 1}^n f (x y_j) \right)^m
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Even in the simplest case $[a,b]=[c,d]=[0,1]$ with $f(x)=x^p$ $(p>0)$, we have $$I=\int_{[0,1]^m}d\mathrm{x}\int_{[0,1]^n}d\mathrm{y}\,\left(x_1^n \cdots x_m^n y_1^m \cdots y_n^m \right)=\frac{1}{(pn+1)^m(pm+1)^n}.$$ In this case, along $m/n \sim \alpha \in (0, 1)$, we have $\log I \sim -(\alpha + 1)n\log n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Lovely. Can this be generalized somehow?